# Openshift Node.JS container, 502 bad gateway error

Tags: node.js, http, openshift

Interesting little story here.

I am running a very sample like application on openshift.
The app works of course.
It works in debug.
It works when I do a wget on openshift's terminal.

It doesn't work at all when I attempt to reach it through the route I have configured.

I have tried all TLS Termination configurations and all I get is a 502 bad gateway error.

8080->8080

Its a very simple app.  And openshift's interface doesn't give you much room for error honestly.  Problem is no logs as to what the router itself is doing that I know how to access.

Comment: Could you perhaps share some of your app configuration files? Is there an API Gateway of some kind in front of your container that needs configuring?

Comment: I think I actually possibly found out what the issue is. I'm not using openshift enterprise but following some troubleshooting steps defined by openshift indicates that its possible the router crashed. The config files are actually good.  But no external route which is so clearly defined, was corresponding to a router IP. I'll doublecheck, as I just deleted my project and added a new one using the nodejs sample project and OF COURSE that worked right out of the box with no real difference in what it was doing.